# MySQL version: 5.5.36 vulnerable?

Tags: mysql, security, pci-compliance

I client of ours did a PCI scan on their site and came up with the following alert:

vulnerable MySQL version: 5.5.36---Risk Level High

Is this version of MySQL in fact more vulnerable than others? Do I need to update the version (which will affect all the sites on the server) or can I tell him otherwise?

Comment: Why dont you ask your client what does Risk Level High means?

Comment: @Mihai He doesn't know. It's a PCI scan, so it's done by third party software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an external scan is detecting MySQL, you've got **huge** problems. You need to firewall that service immediately.

You should not have port 3306 open to the general public under any circumstances, *especially* not if you're trying to get PCI compliance.

Firewall this service completely. If other external servers need access to this, they should do so via a VPN or SSH tunnel. Where this isn't practical, you must employ IP whitelisting at the firewall level.

Comment: Thanks, I closed the port via PLESK.

Answer (score 1):

The threat is real, but it's only in the client:
[CVE-2014-0001](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0001)

That doesn't just mean the command-line client, but any client, such as the MySQL API via PHP, etc.

If your MySQL client library only connects to your server, then there's no threat, as long as your server isn't exploited.

Still, you're unlikely to pass a PCI audit until you update MySQL beyond that version. You should be able to update to the latest 5.5 easily.